# How to get the exact column in Solr search

Tags: mysql, csv, solr

I am using solr to do product search on a csv. The csv contain multiple columns. Is it possible to get the column name where the solr is getting result from along with the complete row?

my search query: "q=XMC LS"
[image: Output of Solr]

The CSV looks something like:
[image: CSV]

Is it possible to get column name "Product" along with the result that is already there?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use [Highlighting](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Highlighting) for that. You highlight every field you search on, and then you will get info on what text, and on what field, matched the query. Look at the docs, there are several different highligthers and many params for each of them.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but now I am facing one more issue. The system works when I keep spaces between search terms but not when I remove it. For eg: "q=PD5 MP2" gives an answer but "q=PD5MP2" doesn't. I know it has something to do with tokenizers but not sure how to do it. I am using Solr 6

Comment: that is a totally different issue, isn't it? you should open a new question, and attache your schema definition for the involved field etc, otherwise it is impossible to help